# ng-repeat-start in table row - count based on ng-show true

Tags: angularjs

I have a table displaying contents based on a ng-show.

```
<tr ng-repeat-start ="row in values" ng-show="applName.indexOf(row.some_name) == -1 || !checkVal"> 
<td></td> 
</tr>
```

`applName` is an array with some values which I want to filter if my check box (`checkVal`)is selected.

I need to count the number of rows actually displayed.

How do I achieve it? I tried having a count, but the count displays the total count and not the acutal count that is displayed.

**Edit:**

I moved the filter logic to controller.

```
<tr ng-repeat-start ="row in results = (values | filter:myFilter('filter_field',chekVal)"> 
<td></td> 
</tr>
{{results.length}}
```

But now since I use pagination, the count will only be the count in that single page and not on the total count across pages. I have to change the logic for pagination?

Comment: Why do you need to count the number of rows actually displayed?

Comment: Try to move show-hide logic to custom filter or component controller. Then list passed to ng-repeat will be already filtered so you can just use `lenght` property.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen To display it.

Comment: @emtei Since I use pagination, the count will only be the count in that single page and not on the total count across pages. I have to change the logic for pagination. Please check the edit for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a custom filter function ng-repeat array and then filter the array depending on condition, with this you wont need ng-show plus you will get exact count

Ex1:

```
 $scope.filterFun= function(){
 // Do some tests

    if(condition)
    {
        return true; // this will be listed in the results
    }

    return false; 
}
 ng-repeat = "result in results | filter:filterFun"
```

Ex2:
---controller code---

```
 function MyCtrl($scope){
        $scope.people = [
            {id: 1, name: "Mark"},
            {id: 2, name: "John"},
            {id:3, name: "Joe"}
        ];
        $scope.myFilter = function(item){
            if(item.id === 1){
                return item;
            }
        };
    }
```

----Html code--

```
 <div ng-app>
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
           <ul>
               <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:myFilter">
                   {{person.id}}
                   -
                   {{person.name}}
               </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Please check the edit section of the question.

Comment: Hi,Your pagination count will be the dependent on the data you are having and the limit set for the same.Can you please tell why do you want the have whole pagination count of all the data elements, even when you want to show only condition satisfying data?

Comment: If I have 100 values and each page shows 10 values, without filtering the total count should show 100. but when filtering is applied, it should show 70(for example). If I try to use {{results.length}}, it only gives total count as 10 as only that is the number of rows rendered in that page.

Comment: It is because you have assigned all the filtered values to your array so at a time it is only showing 10 as per limit "results = (values | filter:myFilter('filter_field',chekVal)" try printing whole array you will only receive 10  elements using the way you have used the filter.try filter using "ng-repeat-start="row in results | filter: myFilter('filter_field',chekVal)" or check  syntax https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter